# How to solve the differential equation of a Brachistochrone Problem

Tags: differential-equations, variational-calculus

This is a differential equation to solve the most brachistochrone line, but it can't find the exact analytical solution :

```
   DSolve[{y''[x] + 1/(2 y[x]) (1 + (y'[x])^2) == 0, y[-1] == 0, 
  y[1] == 0, y'[0] == 0}, y[x], x]
```

But the numerical method can solve it:

```
NDSolve[{y''[x] + 1/(2 y[x]) (1 + (y'[x])^2) == 0, y[-1] == 1, 
  y[1] == 1}, y[x], {x, -1, 1}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. %], {x, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 0.2]
```

Then it can't solve the boundary condition of `{y[-1] == 0, y[1] == 0}`.

How to modify it to obtain analytic solution.

In addition, I prefer to use `DSolve` to solve it, and then the variational method .

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`EulerEquations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/ref/EulerEquations.html) from the built-in [Variational Methods Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/guide/VariationalMethodsPackage.html).

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

sol = DSolve[
  {
   EulerEquations[y''[x] + 1/(2 y[x]) (1 + (y'[x])^2), y[x], x],
   y[-1] == 0,
   y[1] == 0,
   y'[0] == 0
   },
  y[x], x]
```

> ```
> {{y[x] -> 1/2 (1 - x^2)}, {y[x] -> 1/2 (-1 + x^2)}}
> ```

Then

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, -1, 1},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: But we can get the result by solving  `NDSolve[{y''[x] + 1/(2 y[x]) (1 + (y'[x])^2) == 0, y[-1] == 1, 
  y[1] == 1}, y[x], {x, -1, 1}]`, so we can solve this differential equation without using the variational method. I want to solve it with `DSolve` function.